# How cpu is aware of hardware interrupt?

Tags: architecture, operating-system, cpu, interrupt

By wikipedia,

> An interrupt is a signal to the processor
>   emitted by hardware or software indicating an event that needs
>   immediate attention. An interrupt alerts the processor to a
>   high-priority condition requiring the interruption of the current code
>   the processor is executing. The processor responds by suspending its
>   current activities, saving its state, and executing a function called
>   an interrupt handler (or an interrupt service routine, ISR) to deal
>   with the event.

It is written above that the cpu is notified by hardware controller. 
I cannot figure out the process of notification.

Where does the cpu see the existence of interrupt? Is program counter pointer overwritten?
How does cpu decide to stop execution of current task? 
Where is the signal of interrupt stored while cpu is working on the current task?

Comment: The details depend on the particular processor architecture. Interrupts are usually immediate, the current program counter is saved somewhere and the interrupt hander code is the run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hardware interrupts are typically actioned at the end of the current CPU instruction being executed, and are signaled to the CPU by an actual hardware signal - an interrupt request pin/line on the CPU is pulled high/low.  An interrupt-acknowledge hardware cycle is performed instead of excuting the next instruction, the internals of which are architecture-specific, in order to determine which code address to begin execution of the interrupt handler.  The interrupted code PC must be saved somewhere and a memory-protection ring-change may be triggered.  It's an essentially all-hardware operation, but pre-configured by software. You should consult your CPU and interrupt-controller user manuals for full details of the interrupt mechanism, and your OS for its initialization/configuration.

Comment: You mean that the CPU specifically checks for an interrupt signal at the end of every instruction cycle? Doesn't it affect the CPU performance then?

Comment: @darKnight it's implemented in hardware.  There may be an extra gate input somewhere to enable the interrupt ack, but I would expect the overall hit to be insignificant.

Comment: @MartinJames How CPU decides to dispatch the interrupt to which specific ISR? I heard there is something called trap table which contains set of mappings between interrupts and corresponding ISRs. Does hardware (i.e. CPU) do the lookup in the trap table and figure out the right ISR, or hardware just execute a generic interrupt handler and let it figure that out?

Comment: 'It's an essentially all-hardware operation, but pre-configured by software' - if a trap/vector table is used, it must be loaded with the appropriate handler addresses by software before the interrupts are enabled. The interrupt controller hardware can then fetch the correct handler and run it.